# TableViewer initial sorting

Tags: eclipse, jface, rcp, tableviewer

I have a problem with JFace TableViewer in RCP. Basically I have a table with 4 rows, and as input I give an already sorted list of elements. So I expect that first element in my input list is first row in a table. However, the TableViewer reorders the elements, and shows them sorted in DESC order for first column. Since the value I initially sorted is in last column, this totally changes what I want to have.

The questions are:

1. Is there chance to disable this sorting that TableViewer does?
2. If not, what would be the solution of sorting after the input has been set? I have a comparator set that reacts on selection of table header, and sorts the columns, so can I use this for example?

Answer (score 1):

Uf, my mistake.. My comparator was initialized to sort first column in DESC order. So sorry, there is actually no problem :)